# Why am i getting the error "Expected Identifier or"(""

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a sharing action view but on one of my else statements i am getting the error: "Expected Identifier or "("" , i annotated where the error is coming up below:

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {

            SLComposeViewController *tweetForm = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

            //Insert Total Circles Variable!

            [tweetForm setInitialText:@"I just got a score of %d total circles on Circle Creator for iOS, check it out and play for yourself at www.circlecreator.com"];

            [self presentViewController:tweetForm animated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have at least 1 twitter account set up & you are running at least iOS 6, if all fails contact our support email and we will be happy to help." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [alertView show];

        }
    }else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

            SLComposeViewController *facebookForm = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

            //Insert Total Circles Variable!

            [facebookForm setInitialText:@"I just got a score of %d total circles on Circle Creator for iOS, check it out and play for yourself at www.circlecreator.com"];

            [self presentViewController:facebookForm animated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure you have at least 1 Facebook account set up & you are running at least iOS 6, if all fails contact our support email and we will be happy to help." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

            [alertView show];
        }

}else if (buttonIndex == 2) {

    self.emailSenderVC = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
      self.emailSenderVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

       NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just got a score of %d total circles on Circle Creator for iOS,\n check it out and play for yourself at www.circlecreator.com"];
       [self.emailSenderVC setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
      [self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]];
       [self presentViewController:self.emailSenderVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

This is where i am getting the error, could someone please tell me what the problem is as i have spent hours trying to fix it, i would be very grateful :)

```
 //Here is where the error is happening!  
} else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.body = @"I just got a score of %d total circles on Circle Creator for iOS,\n check it out and play for yourself at www.circlecreator.com";
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    }
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. If that's not a copy-paste error, the problem should be obvious then.

Comment: how do i indent the code properly sorry?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about proofreading code to find a typo, and will have no utility for future readers.

Comment: Did you try searching for "xcode indent code"?

Comment: I don't know if it is about proof reading sorry

Comment: re-indenting the code does not fix the error

Comment: @CoconidoHD: it never does. It made it glaringly obvious if you indented the whole method though.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
 //Here is where the error is happening!  
} else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
    MFMessageComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.body = @"I just got a score of %d total circles on Circle Creator for iOS,\n check it out and play for yourself at www.circlecreator.com";
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    }
```

With:

```
else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        viewController.body = @"I just got a score of %d total circles on Circle Creator for iOS,\n check it out and play for yourself at www.circlecreator.com";
        [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

        }

}
```

There is an extra bracket before the last else clause which should actually be in the end.

Error is here too :

```
   NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just got a score of %d total circles on Circle Creator for iOS,\n check it out and play for yourself at www.circlecreator.com"];
```

You are using a placeholder "%d" but not giving a value there.

Should be like this:

```
   NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just got a score of %d total circles on Circle Creator for iOS,\n check it out and play for yourself at www.circlecreator.com", myInt];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check and resolve the other error too, otherwise your app will crash. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, also one thing is that when i try to send a text at the else if == 3 statement i don't know how to make it so that when i click cancel on the message ui it goes back to the app :s

Comment: UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

You can name the cancelButtonTitle, and the cancel button of the UIActionSheet will do its work. :)

Answer (score 3):

the Error is in these lines ->

```
} else if (buttonIndex == 3) {
```

Just remove the closing brace, cause you have already closed it, in previous line.

Comment: i know i haven't done that yet, do you think that is causing the issue a lot further down?

Comment: The main issue is a get an error saying expected identifier or ( at the else if